# ADA 508 - redundant links on page links

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, section508

We have links for Help and Logout in my application. We are using GWT to create form fields. When the user clicks those links a JavaScript `onclick` function will get fired and do the required navigation.

Here is our code..

```
Anchor helpAnc = new Anchor("Help");
Label sep = new Label("|");
Anchor logoutAnc = new Anchor("Logout");        
anchors.add(helpAnc);
anchors.add(sep);
anchors.add(logoutAnc);
```

But when I analyse in WAVE plug-in it is reporting **Redundant link** issue for Logout link. It is due to auto population of `href="javascipt:;"` for both links...

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Anchor` with a `Label` since you are using a `ClickHandler` anyway.

Then style the labels as a link.